# VMware can't start or stop Virtual Ethernet

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-server

Legacy system running CentOS 5 with VMware Server 2.02 (build-203138).

Things were working (relatively) well until recently, when a different machine hosting DNS and DCHP services crashed for unrelated reasons. After that, VMware appears unable to either start or stop, failing on "Virtual Ethernet". The various network bridges report OK (checking /var/log/messages seems to confirm this). 
The only error message reported when starting the service or running vmware-config.pl is `vmnetBridge: Can't connect bridge eth0 to virtual network '0'(Resource deadlock avoided).` (from /var/log/messages)

My theory is that a virtual network daemon crashed during my outage, and left behind a file or PID lock somewhere, but I have no way to confirm, or where such a file might be hidden.

Comment: What is "VMware 2.02"? "VMware" is the name of a company; it makes a number of different products (VMware Workstation, Player, Fusion, Server, vSphere/ESX, ...)

Comment: Sorry, Server. (Edited post accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the vmnet module wasn't able to be loaded onto the kernel (Diagnosed using the --skip-stop-start flag when configuring the server).